# External Library and Project Dependency Question

Tags: c#, wpf

I used an external library - Avalon in my VS solution's project A, and my "startup" project B had referenced project A.

Why when I compile my solution, project B return error?

> Error    1    Unknown build error,
>   'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly
>   'AvalonDock, Version=1.3.3571.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=85a1e0ada7ec13e4'
>   because it has not been preloaded.
>   When using the ReflectionOnly APIs,
>   dependent assemblies must be
>   pre-loaded or loaded on demand through
>   the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve
>   event. Line 89 Position 81.'
>   C:\Net4Project\LI\LI.UI.Views\Main.xaml
>   89    81    LIMS.UI.Views

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to fact that your ProjectA (Avalon) is having some missing DLL 'AvalonDock'

Comment: I had reference AvalonDock.DLL in my Project A. And if I reference AvalonDock.DLL at my Project B too, compile was successful. My question is why I have to reference this DLL at my Project B as well?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure -- but it might be because it's being loaded as reflectiononly -- have you taken a look on google for "reflectiononly"? Brings up [these tips](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/08/24/219691.aspx). Tricky to know whether they apply, as we don't know more about your system.

And adding a [ResolveEventHandler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/11/22/reflection-type-load-exception.aspx) might fix your problem ...